# AVR debugging on Linux with Eclipse and AVaRICE

Tags: avr, debugging

I'd really like to be able to debug on i.e. an Atmega328p on Linux with Eclipse as described on [avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net](http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Debugging)

After quite some research, it seems an JTAGICE mkII should work fine with both avrdude and AVaRICE. But a JTAGICE mkII seems outdated and is quite expensive, besides the clones from Kee Electronics and Waveshare which seem to work fine.

The latest AVaRICE from [SVN](http://svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/avarice/code/trunk%20avarice-code) supports JTAGICE3 but as far as I could find out only with firmware 2.x. There is also the Atmel-ICE Basic but even though it looks similar I was told it is not a JTAGICE3 so it probably won't work with AVaRICE.

So, the only way is to go for one of those JTAGICE mkII clones or is there anything else that works on Linux with Eclipse?

Comment: In case anyone is still looking for a way to debug AVRs on Linux, see my comment on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563910/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-an-avr-microcontroller-using-the-command-line#comment1541137_563910. Bloom supports the MPLAB SNAP, which is a fairly cheap debug tool. Also works with the Atmel-ICE and the Power Debugger. Disclaimer: I am the author of Bloom.

Answer (score 1):

I own ICE, but I do not remeber is it working properly in Eclipse. Avrdude is friendly with ice but only as programmer.

Check please here:

http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/atmel-ice-and-linux

Comment: Interesting thread which confirms what I found out but I wonder why nobody mentions the JTAGICE mkII clones since I have read that at least the Kee Electronics one works. And I really don't feel like debugging or even developing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a partial answer to my own question:

I have contacted both Kee Electronics and Waveshare about Linux compatibility of their JTAGICEmkII clones. Waveshare just pointed me to a tiny FAQ that says nothing about Linux compatibility, and Kee Electronics said their debugger is fully compatible with the JTAGICEmkII on Windows but they don't have personal experience with Linux.

So I got myself a used Atmel JTAGICEmkII and tried it out.

It works fine as programmer, and also debugging works (also in Eclipse), besides that execution won't stop at the breakpoints, which I think is related to debugWire. A usable workaround is to set permanent breakpoints.

Here is a [related question with some details](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/221970/65699).

For anyone interested, I've written down all I have learned about AVR debugging (with debugWire) on Linux with Eclipse [here](http://luniks.net/avr-debug.php).

I'll be happy to try out any suggestion and update the document.